# How can I solve this function with list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
    yearlist = []
    unluckydates = []
    for year in range(end):
        unluckydates = unlucky(year)
        if len(unluckydates) == 3:
            yearlist.append(year)
    return yearlist
```

Here's what each of the variables is used for:

`unlucky(year)` is a function that accepts the year and returns the unlucky dates (Friday 13th) in a list.

`unluckydates` is used to store the list from `unlucky(year)`

`yearlist` is used to store years that have 3 unlucky dates (Friday 13th)

The function returns a list of all the years from 0 to 2016 that have 3 unlucky dates. I wrote it this way, now, I want to know how I can write it using list comprehension.

Here's the line I came up with:

`yearlist.append([(unlucky(year), unluckydates == unlucky(year)) for year in range(0, end) if len(unluckydates) == 3])`

Comment: Isn't that already the data you need? Just return that list comprehension. Side note, I'm amazed that for loop works. You're setting the loop iterator, then using it as both the iterator and the start argument to range, AND incrementing it in your loop.

Comment: It is weird to do `year += 1` in a `for year in ...` loop

Comment: you have same variable in  `for year in range(year, end):` and `year += 1`

Comment: @trincot It is... who put that there... <.<

Comment: `[year for year in range(end) if len(unlucky(year)) == 3]`  you don't even need to store the return value of `unlucky` in anything, if you don't use it later

Comment: @MorganThrapp The part I came up with is not working. Idk where I went wrong. But yeah, the function works.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen It's part of the question. Besides... isn't it good to learn how to write functions various ways?

Comment: @trayceetrace I was out of place,  I'm sorry, I personally don't much like long one liners but yes it is completely valid to wonder how it would work.  I think I need to go lie down though you are the third person I've given a hard time today...

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Ahahaa, that's fine. I asked myself the same thing when I saw the question!

Comment: Actually if you don't necessarily need a list but just want to iterate over the values I'd recommend you write this as [a generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) by replacing the `yearlist.append(year)` with just `yield year`, removing the return statement and `yearlist = []` then when checking the output just iterate over it or do `list(mostUnlucky1(2017))`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Interesting... Thanks for the introduction to generators!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
def mostUnlucky1(end):
    return [year for year in range(end) if len(unlucky(year)) == 3]
```

Note that since the target variable of the for loop is named `year` (means it gets a new value at every iteration), the `year += 1` at the end of the for loop is redundant.

And you can drop the zero start index for `range`.